# shorter way to get data attributes from all column names and values

Tags: php, mysql

table users has 14 columns - id, src link, title...

```
function get_atitles(){
    global $db;
    $st = $db->query("select * from users order by name asc");
    $arr = $st->fetchAll();
    $ht = '';
    foreach($arr as $el){
        $ht .= "<div class='atitle' data-id= " . $el['id'] . " data-src='" . $el['src'] . "... and so on for all of the 14 columns...>" . $el['title'] . "</div>\n";
    }
    echo $ht;
}
```

Is there a shorter way, like this:

```
foreach($arr as $el){
            $ht .= "<div class='atitle' 
                 //foreach column in users $ht .= "data-" . column_name = column_value
            $ht .= ">" . $el['title'] . "</div>\n";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
function get_atitles(){
    global $db;
    $st = $db->query("select * from users order by name asc");
    $arr = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $ht = '';
    foreach($arr as $el){
        $ht = $ht . "<div class='atitle' ";
        foreach($el as $key=>$col)
            if($key != 'title')
                $ht .= "data-".$key.'="'.$col.'" '; 
        $ht.= '>'.$el['title'] . "</div>\n";
    }
    echo $ht;
}
```

Comment: it works but there is double data - data-id = 0 data-0 = 0... etc

Comment: can you please post a sample of $arr so that i can test is on my pc? or post the generated html code on your question @qadenza

Comment: @qadenza it's because of how PDO fetch data (https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), consider using `->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` instead of `->fetchAll()`

Comment: using `->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` I'm getting error - `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: @qadenza sorry i meant to say `->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: `->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` - works, thanks a lot

Comment: @qadenza excellent, feel free to remark the answer as correct ahah